# When is the class constructor called while deserialising using XmlSerializer.Deserialize?

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

My application saves a class away using XmlSerializer, and then later when required, creates an instance by deserialising it again.
I would like to use some property members of my class (assigned during deserialisation) in my constructor logic. It is ok to assume that the properties will be assigned first, and once all properties are assigned will the constructor be called?

Continuing on this topic, is there any documentation available on the sequence of events that take place during deserialisation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No it is not OK to assume the properties will be set when the constructor runs.  The opposite is true.  The constructor is the very first piece of code which runs when an instance of an object is created.  It's not possible for the properties to be set until after the constructor has started executing.

The XML deserialization process roughly looks like the following

- Call the parameterless constructor
- Set the properties to their deserialized values

A way to work around this is to use a factory method to do the deserialization and then run the logic which depends on the properties being set.  For example

```
class MyClass {
  ...
  public static MyClass Deserialize(string xmlContents) {
    var local = ... // Do the XML deserialization
    local.PostCreateLogic();
    return local;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's true for XmlSerializer, but some serializers do not call the constructor at all when deserializing an object.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/9419743/141172

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is the creation of your object. Your object need to be created before assign properties value. Then, the constructor will be called first.

I don't know any documentation for the sequence. But if your class isn't so big, it's possible to add some breakpoint and you'll see which events is first.